# Seeing 30–40 Point Differences Between Lighthouse and Page Speed Insights

Tags: google-pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

When running a Google Lighthouse test I'm consistently seeing performance scores 30 to 40 points higher than I'm seeing looking at the same page on Google Pagespeed Insights.

Does anyone know why this may be the case? Which set of results are should I concern myself with?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: what parameters are you sending to lighthouse (also which version of Lighthouse.....Google API, self hosted CLI, in browser via developer tools?). Odds are you do not have the same configuration for both tests but there isn't enough info here to help you pinpoint what at the moment.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, browser via dev tools. See config above. Only change I made to the settings was turning off the other categories.

Comment: Thanks, based on that we rule out user error :-) hehe. Do you want to share your page URL so I can have a peak? It can be a multitude of things such as CDN settings, erroneous robots.txt entries etc. What is your PSI score and Developer tools score so I can compare at my side and where in the world are you located (country)?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, as of just now, seeing 89 mobile and 100 desktop on Lighthouse, 44 mobile and 79 desktop on PageSpeed Insights. Also running in Incognito mode with all extensions disabled.

Located in the US, [site is here](https://hockmeyer.com).

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into it for you. Few more questions (sorry you seem to know what you are doing but I get similar score to PSI, albeit from UK). What version of Chrome are you running, do you have anything setup like a modified windows hosts file, do you have a monstrously powerful CPU (single core performance). I ask as there is massive JS execution time stats (4s). This would affect your score a lot more in Lighthouse v5 rather than v6. The only other thing that comes to mind at the moment is the CPU slowdown part isn't working correctly on your install (hence asking about CPU speed)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, using Edge 85, though the same is true of Chrome 85.

Workin' with a MacBook Pro (2019) w/ 2.3 GHz Intel Core i9 processor if I'm reading your question correctly.